# Do you know any framework / application to create a google map based web application

Tags: google-maps

I want to create a web application which makes use of Google maps.
Features are quite simple:

- Users can login (best with FB connect)
- Users can post items which are geolocated
- UI consists mainly of a google map with all items

I'm looking for something implemented where you would only have to specify the nature of your items.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to make money off of it, you can use ESRI's Javascript API for free:

[ArcGIS Javascript API](http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/)